# 2Checkout INS all Notification failed

Tags: php, 2checkout

I'm new to this 2checkout payment gateway. I have done payment integration successfully. But in my sandbox account all ins notification listed in failed.
I fully searched this problem, but still no one explaining this problem. please anyone explain this problem.

Comment: I am also having the same issue with sandbox account. Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

INS notifications doesn't work if DEMO mode is enabled.
To disable it go to Sandbox admin panel -> Select "Account" tab -> "Site Management"
Demo setting should be set to Off or Parameter if no 'demo' parameter is not sent.

Comment: Still not getting the INS even after changing the demo setting to off

Comment: I have resolved my issue and get INS working properly by contacting 2checkout support team. They answer within a day or so. You may contact them via techsupport@2checkout.com

Comment: Did they mention any reason why INS was not working? Does the issue persist on 2checkout side?

Comment: INS is working. I don't remember what was the problem, but I wasn't able to resolve it only with reading the official docs and googling, so I contacted them and the assist.